# How to stop UNUserNotificationCenter using UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I have an UNUserNotificationCenter that send local notification every 60 secondes. It is implemented like below:

```
    let userNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notificationContent.title = "Test title"
    notificationContent.body = "Test body"

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60,
                                                    repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testNotification",
                                        content: notificationContent,
                                        trigger: trigger)

    userNotificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Notification Error: ", error)
        }
    }
```

It works well but I can't stop it and it continues to send notifications even if my app is killed.

What is the best way to stop UNUserNotificationCenter to send notifications in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to call `removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers:)` and pass in the identifiers for which you need to cancel the scheduled, but undelivered notifications.

```
userNotificationCenter.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["testNotification"])
```

Or if you want to remove all pending notifications for your app, you can call `removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()` instead.